# Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): error

Tags: php, mysql, css, html

I'm getting the following error for that perticular line and I'm not sure what's wrong here. Could someone help please?

```
if ($updbS == "Books" || $updbS == "Pens") {
$querySf = "SELECT SUM(db1) AS stationery FROM db2 WHERE items = '$low'"; 
$resultSf = mysql_query($querySf); 
$rSf = mysql_fetch_array($resultSf); **//Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource...**
$totalSf = $rSf['stationery']; 
$totTMonth = $totalSf;
if ($totTMonth==''){
    $totTMonth = '0';
}
```

Comment: Are you [connecting](http://us2.php.net/function.mysql-connect) to your db? Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Instead you should consider ***mysqli*** or ***PDO*** functions.

Comment: check for `mysql_error`, it seems that your query is failing. Also note that mysql_* functions are deprecated. use mysqli or PDO..

Comment: Don't use mysql_*. Use PDO or mysqli_* instead.

Comment: `or die(mysql_error())`

Comment: Funny, that's what you wrote @T0xicCode

Comment: @Fred-ii- no. using `or die()` is [bad practice](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die). My posted answer handles the error in a sane way, not by panicking and ending the response.

Comment: I agree on that. Mine was just a quick example, one method of many. @T0xicCode

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` is probably getting an error and returning  false. You should check for that like follow:

```
if ($resultSf === false) {
    $error = mysql_error();
} else {
    $rSf = mysql_fetch_array($resultSf); **//Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource...**
    $totalSf = $rSf['stationery']; 
    $totTMonth = $totalSf;
    if ($totTMonth==''){
        $totTMonth = '0';
    }
}
```

You should switch to the MySQLi or PDO extension for database access though.

Comment: Thanks. There is no error. But when I included the if ($resultSf === false) { line it doesn't show any error? Why is that?

Comment: There is an error. My code checks if an error occurred, and if it detects one, it places the information in `$error`. Print it, and it will tell you what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

You're query is probably not succeeding.

Where do you connect to the db?
What happens if you var_dump $resultSf?